# How to remove lag during data fetching from large text files from my code in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text file consisting of 21000 lines, i have an attribute and i need to search it in the .txt file and need to return a value from the same too. All code is done and tried async plus new thread but there is a five second lag during the button click . how can i remove the lag.

Tried on new unity and C#

```
public async void read()
{
    string[] lines = await ReadAllLinesAsync("Assets/Blockchain Module/" + File + ".csv");
    fields = null;

    for (int j = 0; j < lines.Length; j++)
    {
        fields = lines[j].Split(',');
        x[j] = System.Convert.ToDouble(fields[1]);
        y[j] = System.Convert.ToDouble(fields[2]);
        z[j] = System.Convert.ToDouble(fields[3]);
        temp[j] = System.Convert.ToDouble(fields[4]);
    }
}

public void Start()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(read);
    thread.Start();

    //gradient.Evaluate()
    //var main = particleSystem.main;
    //main.maxParticles = 200;
}

private const FileOptions DefaultOptions = FileOptions.Asynchronous | FileOptions.SequentialScan;

public static Task<string[]> ReadAllLinesAsync(string path) => ReadAllLinesAsync(path, Encoding.UTF8);

public static async Task<string[]> ReadAllLinesAsync(string path, Encoding encoding)
{
    var lines = new List<string>();

    // Open the FileStream with the same FileMode, FileAccess
    // and FileShare as a call to File.OpenText would've done.
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, DefaultBufferSize, DefaultOptions))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }

    return lines.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I was reading your code and I saw that you use async voids. If I where you I would change that to an async Task. You should avoid async voids by any costs if available. And in C# it's common to use `var` in stead of `string[]` to define variables

Comment: Thank you, But would that reduce the lag i am experiencing ?

Comment: I would doubt that. But it can be if you have a lot of async calls without configure awaits.

Comment: I am new to programming. Can you elaborate on the lot of async calls ?

Comment: `async void` prevents the async/await system from working properly.

Comment: Well you can read more about that in https://www.infoworld.com/article/3126293/best-practices-in-net-asynchronous-programming.html

Comment: And you can read more about configureing the awaits in https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f

Comment: Thank you amy but i do not have anything else to return so i should choose any other type with return 0 ?

Comment: Thank you Stuiterslurf , let me check on that!

Comment: If you cange your async void to a task you can await it in the task and return when you need.

Comment: @Pacub If you don't return `Task` from an `async` function, you *prevent* the async system from functioning properly.  Read the two articles you've already been given.

Comment: Okay but still is it a solution to my lag problem during data fetch ?

Comment: @Pacub I would also suggest you give the task propper naming. So if the async task is `Read` you would name it `ReadAsync` so you know that you need to `configureawait`.

Comment: @Pacub I don't think it will be the solotuion to your lag problem during the fetch. It's just how you propperly program async C# to reduce the amount of bugs

Comment: @StuiterSlurf  I understood that my way using async and await is not the good version but i just need a solution to my slow fetch of data or the lag or a better way to reduce the time taken ! currently it takes around 5-7 sec lag for data fetch only, i mean to the arrays!

Comment: @Amy I understood that my way using async and await is not the good version but i just need a solution to my slow fetch of data or the lag or a better way to reduce the time taken ! currently it takes around 5-7 sec lag for data fetch only, i mean to the arrays!

Comment: @Pacub If you just try this out, it might work for your loading lag. Depending on when you load this in. If it's in-game, you still have lag. But you say in Unity but the tag is for asp.net. Are you building a website or a game?

Answer (score 2):

In general if your search is line based is better to read line one by one instead to read all the file:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("filename"))
{
    while (true)
    {
        string line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        if (line == null)
        {
             break;
        }
        //logic here...
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show by  helping me with a better code of what i have written because i need array version of the same like i created!

Comment: Well since you are parsing the fiel, dont store the whole file, but just what you are extracting, maybe once at startup, as said in other answers

Answer (score 2):

Reading and parsing the file apparently costs 5 seconds on your system. I don't think reading it line by line is the fastest approach, but anyway, don't parse the file for each request.

Read it once on application startup, and cache it in an appropriate data type.

Comment: Can you please elaborate based on the code, i am a newbie on coding , i couldnt follow your answer!

Comment: If line by line is not the best approach , which is the best according to you and how to make it into an array based on my code ?